# locating files in a web server hacking(prevention)

Tags: php, database

i have some questions concerning on how you get the file name and/or directory in the server/ web server  that is hosting a website. PLS NOTE the website was my trial run with no security for the backbone

Can anybody help me with this one? on how to secure my files and folders with security? also im using php, html, css, javascript(ajax), jquery for the sample sites and i have no idea in security can anyone help me with this one and how can i do this, especially in sql injection and ,xss tips and or sites that i can reviews on the subject matter would really be nice and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page for the most common attacks and prevention tips.